# Are approval requests that are submitted to queues distributed or shared among the users of the queue?

Tags: approval-process, queue, approval-step

I'm trying to create an approval process using a pool of users as approvers, but I don't know the full mechanics of Queues.

When a document is submitted to a queue for an approval, does that document get put into a shared pool, where any of the queue users can approve the document, or does the document get assigned to a single approver among that queue that has sole responsibility to approve said document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this source](https://patlatus.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/who-can-be-approvers-in-approval-process-in-salesforce/):

> When the assigned approver is a queue :
>
> - **Any queue member can approve or reject an approval request that is assigned to the queue.**
> - Approval request emails are sent to the queue email address. If the queue is set up to send email to members, then approval request emails
>     are also sent to the queue members, except those whose approval user
>     preferences are set to never receive approval request emails.
> - When an approval request is assigned to a queue, each queue member’s delegated approver also receives an approval request email
>     notification.
> - Because email notifications to a queue aren’t intended for an external audience, any instances of the merge field
>     {!ApprovalRequest.External_URL} in the email template are sent as the
>     equivalent internal URL.
> - Salesforce1 notifications for approval requests aren’t sent to queues. For each approval step involving a queue, we recommend adding
>     individual users as assigned approvers, so at least those individuals
>     can receive the approval request notifications in Salesforce1. To have
>     both queues and individual users as assigned approvers, select
>     Automatically assign to approver(s) instead of Automatically assign to
>     queue in the approval step.
> - When an approval request is rejected and returned to the previous approver and the previous approver was a queue, the approval request
>     is assigned to the user who approved it instead of the queue.
> - The Approval History related list displays the queue name in the Assigned To column and the actual user who approved or rejected the
>     approval request in the Actual Approver column.